# How can I solve this problem related to the installation of GMP using VCPKG?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, libraries, build-error, vcpkg

**When I try to install GMP with VCPKG for visual studio, it gives me this error:**

```
    ./vcpkg install gmp
Computing installation plan...
The following packages will be built and installed:
    gmp[core]:x86-windows
Detecting compiler hash for triplet x86-windows...
Starting package 1/1: gmp:x86-windows
Building package gmp[core]:x86-windows...
Could not locate cached archive: C:\Users\utente\AppData\Local\vcpkg\archives\ae\aee4cb498b812554294e4bbc47b9469351282935.zip
-- Using cached C:/Users/utente/Documents/Visual Studio 2019/vcpkg/downloads/ShiftMediaProject-gmp-e140dfc8668e96d7e56cbd46467945adcc6b3cc4.tar.gz
-- Cleaning sources at C:/Users/utente/Documents/Visual Studio 2019/vcpkg/buildtrees/gmp/src/adcc6b3cc4-2b6258d695.clean. Use --editable to skip cleaning for the packages you specify.
-- Extracting source C:/Users/utente/Documents/Visual Studio 2019/vcpkg/downloads/ShiftMediaProject-gmp-e140dfc8668e96d7e56cbd46467945adcc6b3cc4.tar.gz
-- Applying patch vs.build.patch
-- Applying patch runtime.patch
-- Applying patch prefix.patch
-- Using source at C:/Users/utente/Documents/Visual Studio 2019/vcpkg/buildtrees/gmp/src/adcc6b3cc4-2b6258d695.clean
-- Building SMP/libgmp.sln for Release
CMake Error at scripts/cmake/vcpkg_execute_required_process.cmake:72 (message):
    Command failed: msbuild "C:/Users/utente/Documents/Visual Studio 2019/vcpkg/buildtrees/gmp/x86-windows-rel/adcc6b3cc4-2b6258d695.clean/SMP/libgmp.sln" /p:Configuration=ReleaseDLL /p:UseEnv=True /t:Rebuild /p:Platform=x86 /p:PlatformToolset=v142 /p:VCPkgLocalAppDataDisabled=true /p:UseIntelMKL=No /p:WindowsTargetPlatformVersion=10.0.18362.0 /p:VcpkgTriplet=x86-windows "/p:VcpkgCurrentInstalledDir=C:/Users/utente/Documents/Visual Studio 2019/vcpkg/installed/x86-windows" /p:VcpkgManifestInstall=false /m "/p:ForceImportBeforeCppTargets=C:/Users/utente/Documents/Visual Studio 2019/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/msbuild/vcpkg.targets" /p:VcpkgApplocalDeps=false
    Working Directory: C:/Users/utente/Documents/Visual Studio 2019/vcpkg/buildtrees/gmp/x86-windows-rel/adcc6b3cc4-2b6258d695.clean
    Error code: 1
    See logs for more information:
      C:\Users\utente\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\vcpkg\buildtrees\gmp\build-x86-windows-rel-out.log

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  scripts/cmake/vcpkg_install_msbuild.cmake:162 (vcpkg_execute_required_process)
  ports/gmp/portfile.cmake:48 (vcpkg_install_msbuild)
  scripts/ports.cmake:79 (include)


Error: Building package gmp:x86-windows failed with: BUILD_FAILED
Please ensure you're using the latest portfiles with `.\vcpkg update`, then
submit an issue at https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/issues including:
  Package: gmp:x86-windows
  Vcpkg version: 2020.06.15-nohash
```

****I tried to install GMP on another PC and it gives the same error, I also tried to uninstall and
re-install visual studio and vcpkg but nothing changed.****

Answer (score 1):

First, I suggest you update `vcpkg` to the latest version.

If it does not work, check if the language setting of Visual Studio is English, if not, you could select `Tools->Options->Environment->International Settings` and set `English` in Visual Studio.

Finally, if the problem still cannot be solved, please show me the content of `C:\Users\utente\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\vcpkg\buildtrees\gmp\build-x86-windows-rel-out.log` .

Also, you could refer to this [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/issues/1833) for more information.